# Intent.createChooser closes fragment

Tags: android, file, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using the aFileChooser in a `fragment`.
When I select the files the `fragment` is ended, restarting the activity.

I am using android cersion 4.4.4 for testing

Here is the code i am using for selecting file :

```
private void showChooser() {
    // Use the GET_CONTENT intent from the utility class
    Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
    // Create the chooser Intent
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, getString(R.string.choose_file_type));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // The reason for the existence of aFileChooser
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            // If the file selection was successful
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    // Get the URI of the selected file
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        // Get the file path from the URI
                        final String path = FileUtils.getPath(getContext(), uri);
                        mGlobals.toastError("File Selected: " + path);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FileSelectorTestActivity", "File select error", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**LogCat** Error Log:

```
02-05 12:20:08.376: D/TEST(24355): ***************** startActivityForResult *****************
02-05 12:20:08.381: I/ActivityManager(1088): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras)} from pid 24355
02-05 12:20:08.384: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:08.466: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:08.485: D/bsthal(1088): setDelay, handle: 1598182229 delay: 200000000
02-05 12:20:08.485: E/bsthal(1088): <BST> set delay: 200000000ns
02-05 12:20:08.485: I/bsthal(1088): <BST> set delay of <BOSCH BMC150 Acceleration Sensor> to 200ms
02-05 12:20:08.487: D/bsthal(1088): activate, handle: 1598182229, enabled: 0, index 0
02-05 12:20:08.487: E/bsthal(1088): <BST> disable accel, orig state: 1
02-05 12:20:08.487: I/bsthal(1088): <BST> disable sensor <BOSCH BMC150 Acceleration Sensor>
02-05 12:20:08.488: D/bsthal(1088): activate, handle: 1598182230, enabled: 0, index 1
02-05 12:20:08.488: I/bsthal(1088): <BST> disable sensor <BOSCH BMC150 Magnetic Field Sensor>
02-05 12:20:08.488: D/bsthal(1088): activate, handle: 1598182231, enabled: 0, index 5
02-05 12:20:08.544: W/IntentResolver(1088): resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
02-05 12:20:08.556: W/IntentResolver(1088): resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
02-05 12:20:08.566: I/ActivityManager(1088): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity} from pid 24355
02-05 12:20:08.568: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:08.573: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:08.601: W/IntentResolver(1088): resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: RGURRAM_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.056+PATCH[ES]_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_ENGG ()
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): Build Date: 05/27/14 Tue
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): Local Branch: 
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.2
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): Local Patches: f0931b5dfb60c536e5444f9053822ad191929528 ES2.0: Fix for seg fault in VBO validation
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041):                  0c6f7c995c347b2eb54a9baa340cab69ba279634 es20: Remove extra-logging info
02-05 12:20:08.619: I/Adreno-EGL(25041): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04
02-05 12:20:08.712: I/LaunchCheckinHandler(1088): Displayed com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity,wp,ca,141
02-05 12:20:08.712: I/ActivityManager(1088): Displayed com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity: +141ms (total +250ms)
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041): Current stack: 
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  * Root{authority=com.google.android.apps.docs.storage, rootId=1, title=Drive}
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  +-- Document{docId=acc=1;doc=6, name=NucleoVacinacaoHMV}
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  +-- Document{docId=acc=1;doc=3, name=Movvy}
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  +-- Document{docId=acc=1;doc=96, name=Constat}
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  +-- Document{docId=acc=1;view=mydrive, name=Meu Drive}
02-05 12:20:08.719: D/Documents(25041):  +-- Document{docId=acc=1;0, name=foo@bar.com}
02-05 12:20:08.758: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155
02-05 12:20:08.758: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState
02-05 12:20:08.758: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
02-05 12:20:08.771: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X
02-05 12:20:08.795: D/Documents(25041): userMode=0, userSortOrder=0 --> mode=1, sortOrder=1
02-05 12:20:09.108: W/ManagedEGLContext(24355): doTerminate failed: EGL count is 3 but managed count is 1
02-05 12:20:09.215: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572
02-05 12:20:09.215: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState
02-05 12:20:09.215: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState
02-05 12:20:09.230: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X
02-05 12:20:10.147: I/ActivityManager(1088): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* flg=0x1000000 cmp=com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity} from pid 25041

02-05 12:20:10.151: I/SFPerfTracer(293):      triggers: (rate: 46:1405) (compose: 0:27) (post: 0:1) (render: 15:456) (0:50588 frames) (1:175892)

02-05 12:20:10.151: D/SFPerfTracer(293):        layers: (3:12) (DimLayer: 0:210)* (FocusedStackFrame: 0:2375)* (StatusBar: 0:22293) (NavigationBar: 0:13540) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper: 0:533)* (DimLayer: 0:24)* (DimLayer: 0:6)* (com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity: 0:28)* (SurfaceView: 0:128)* (br.com.constat.movvycms/br.com.constat.movvy.MainActivity: 0:49)* (com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity: 1:49) 
02-05 12:20:10.154: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:10.181: I/SFPerfTracer(293):      triggers: (rate: 0:7) (5833 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (10:218212 vsyncs) (12:308581)
02-05 12:20:10.186: W/ContextImpl(1324): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1252 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:365 com.motorola.motocare.util.TriggerHelper$TriggerBuilder.send:76 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.PauseResumeTrigger.handleFrameworkEvent:53 com.motorola.motocare.internal.frameworkevents.FwEventMonitor$FrameworkListener.processFrameworkEvent:114 
02-05 12:20:10.214: I/Gallery(25087): Gallery version : 303009
02-05 12:20:10.214: V/StateManager(25087): startState class com.android.gallery3d.app.AlbumSetPage

02-05 12:20:10.216: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572

02-05 12:20:10.216: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:10.216: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:10.222: D/Gallery.MultiSetSync(25087): onSyncDone: ************* #pending=1

02-05 12:20:10.222: D/Gallery.MultiSetSync(25087):   request sync: *************

02-05 12:20:10.223: D/Gallery.MultiSetSync(25087): onSyncDone: ****** #pending=0

02-05 12:20:10.223: D/Gallery.MultiSetSync(25087):   request sync: ******

02-05 12:20:10.232: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: RGURRAM_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.056+PATCH[ES]_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_ENGG ()

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): Build Date: 05/27/14 Tue

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): Local Branch: 

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.2

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): Local Patches: f0931b5dfb60c536e5444f9053822ad191929528 ES2.0: Fix for seg fault in VBO validation

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087):                  0c6f7c995c347b2eb54a9baa340cab69ba279634 es20: Remove extra-logging info

02-05 12:20:10.253: I/Adreno-EGL(25087): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04

02-05 12:20:10.343: I/GLRootView(25087): onSurfaceChanged: 720x1184, gl10: com.google.android.gles_jni.GLImpl@423b8aa8

02-05 12:20:10.343: I/GLRootView(25087): layout content pane 720x1184 (compensation 0)

02-05 12:20:10.386: I/LaunchCheckinHandler(1088): Displayed com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity,wp,ca,203

02-05 12:20:10.386: I/ActivityManager(1088): Displayed com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity: +203ms

02-05 12:20:10.570: W/LocalImage(25087): failed to get thumbnail from: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Movvy/IMG_20150129_173926_-1630555450.jpg

02-05 12:20:10.571: D/skia(25087): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

02-05 12:20:10.571: D/skia(25087): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

02-05 12:20:10.572: W/ImageCacheRequest(25087): decode orig failed /local/image/item/8905,1422560366,MICROTHUMB

02-05 12:20:10.650: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_CONCURRENT freed 14832K, 63% free 15269K/40772K, paused 6ms+9ms, total 45ms

02-05 12:20:10.650: D/dalvikvm(25087): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms

02-05 12:20:10.654: D/dalvikvm(25087): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms

02-05 12:20:10.702: I/SFPerfTracer(293):      triggers: (rate: 46:1406) (compose: 0:27) (post: 0:1) (render: 15:458) (14:50606 frames) (15:175920)

02-05 12:20:10.702: D/SFPerfTracer(293):        layers: (6:11) (DimLayer: 0:210)* (FocusedStackFrame: 0:2379)* (StatusBar: 14:22307) (NavigationBar: 0:13540) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper: 0:533)* (DimLayer: 0:24)* (DimLayer: 0:7) (com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity: 15:73) (com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity: 15:24) (SurfaceView: 15:21) 

02-05 12:20:10.726: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 59% free 17087K/40772K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 30ms

02-05 12:20:10.726: D/dalvikvm(25087): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms

02-05 12:20:10.726: D/dalvikvm(25087): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms

02-05 12:20:10.825: D/Ulp_jni(1088): Location CB invoked

02-05 12:20:10.825: V/XTWIFI-ULP(1088): [MessageQ_Client] creating client socket

02-05 12:20:10.826: I/XTWIFI-ULP(1088): [MessageQ_Client] connecting to server [/data/misc/location/mq/location-mq-s]

02-05 12:20:10.826: E/XTWIFI-ULP(1088): [MessageQ_Client] connect error: 2, [No such file or directory]

02-05 12:20:10.826: E/XTWIFI-ULP(1088): [MessageQ_Client] connect failed 3

02-05 12:20:10.826: D/Ulp_jni(1088): ulp_network_location_request_cb invoked

02-05 12:20:10.830: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 3500

02-05 12:20:10.832: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): SET-REQUEST

02-05 12:20:10.832: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 20000

02-05 12:20:10.845: D/WifiService(1088): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42a5b648}

02-05 12:20:10.846: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=131143

02-05 12:20:10.846: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:10.846: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:10.847: I/wpa_supplicant(1193): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:10.848: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:10.848: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:10.848: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:10.870: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_CONCURRENT freed 108K, 52% free 19577K/40772K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 26ms

02-05 12:20:10.928: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateTelephonySignalStrength[0]: iconList[iconLevel]=7f020298/zz_moto_stat_sys_signal_3_fully_wide iconLevel=3 mMSimMobileInetCondition=1 mMSimMobileInetConditionSB=1

02-05 12:20:10.928: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: subscription=0

02-05 12:20:10.929: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: dataSub=0

02-05 12:20:10.929: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: SimState=READY

02-05 12:20:10.931: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): notifySignalsChangedCallbacks[0]: isEmergencyOnly(0)=false enabled=true sim=(none)="(empty)" signal=zz_moto_stat_sys_signal_3_fully_wide="Três barras de sinal do telefone." roaming=(none)="Não está em roaming."

02-05 12:20:10.931: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174):  type=zz_moto_stat_sys_data_suspended_h_wide="3.5G" activity=(none)="(empty)"

02-05 12:20:10.931: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174):  slot=1="1" network="Claro BR"

02-05 12:20:10.978: D/dalvikvm(23523): GC_EXPLICIT freed 251K, 46% free 9357K/17256K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 22ms

02-05 12:20:11.015: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 143K, 45% free 22796K/40772K, paused 17ms, total 17ms

02-05 12:20:11.218: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572

02-05 12:20:11.218: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.218: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.253: D/dalvikvm(1088): GC_EXPLICIT freed 986K, 39% free 23952K/38820K, paused 4ms+11ms, total 128ms

02-05 12:20:11.277: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 226K, 34% free 26990K/40772K, paused 19ms, total 20ms

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/TCMD(497): NL - Read 56 bytes from update socket.

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/TCMD(497): NL - message type is RTM_NEWLINK

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/TCMD(497): Listening for incoming client connection request

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-ADDED 286

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-BSS-ADDED 286

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 

02-05 12:20:11.416: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 

02-05 12:20:11.423: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=147461

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectModeState

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: DriverStartedState

02-05 12:20:11.424: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: SupplicantStartedState

02-05 12:20:11.431: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:11.471: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_CONCURRENT freed 149K, 20% free 32811K/40772K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 24ms

02-05 12:20:11.528: D/LBSSystemMonitorService(1088): handleMessage what - 3

02-05 12:20:11.528: D/Wiper_jni(1088): Send Network Location.

02-05 12:20:11.547: D/dalvikvm(1594): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2001K, 33% free 11699K/17256K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 52ms

02-05 12:20:11.583: D/WifiService(1088): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42a5b648}

02-05 12:20:11.655: D/Ulp_jni(1088): ulp_network_location_request_cb invoked

02-05 12:20:11.657: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 3500

02-05 12:20:11.657: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): SET-REQUEST

02-05 12:20:11.657: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 20000

02-05 12:20:11.657: D/Wiper_jni(1088): wifiRequestEventCb invoked

02-05 12:20:11.657: D/LBSSystemMonitorService(1088): handleMessage what - 2

02-05 12:20:11.658: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): onSetRequest: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 600000

02-05 12:20:11.662: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): SET-REQUEST

02-05 12:20:11.662: V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi(1594): in Handler: ProviderRequestUnbundled, reportLocation is true and interval is 600000

02-05 12:20:11.672: D/WifiService(1088): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42a5b648}

02-05 12:20:11.673: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=131143

02-05 12:20:11.673: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.673: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.674: I/wpa_supplicant(1193): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:11.674: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:11.674: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 

02-05 12:20:11.675: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:11.709: I/WindowState(1088): WIN DEATH: Window{42a23818 u0 br.com.constat.movvycms/br.com.constat.movvy.MainActivity}

02-05 12:20:11.709: I/ActivityManager(1088): Process br.com.constat.movvycms (pid 24355) has died.

02-05 12:20:11.734: I/SFPerfTracer(293):       trigger: frame rate (-40.930%)   (35.442 fps)    (28.215 ms)     (5 drops)   (13 frames)

02-05 12:20:11.734: I/SFPerfTracer(293):      triggers: (rate: 47:1413) (compose: 0:27) (post: 0:1) (render: 15:458) (13:50634 frames) (14:175954)

02-05 12:20:11.734: D/SFPerfTracer(293):        layers: (3:11) (DimLayer: 0:210)* (FocusedStackFrame: 0:2380)* (StatusBar: 1:22315)* (NavigationBar: 0:13540) (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper: 0:533)* (DimLayer: 0:24)* (DimLayer: 0:8)* (com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity: 0:77)* (com.motorola.MotGallery2/com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity: 0:29) (SurfaceView: 14:55) 

02-05 12:20:11.739: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=131143

02-05 12:20:11.739: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.739: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.740: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:11.744: D/dalvikvm(23523): GC_EXPLICIT freed 305K, 46% free 9368K/17256K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 36ms

02-05 12:20:11.772: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=131155

02-05 12:20:11.772: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.772: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:11.799: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 174K, 3% free 39783K/40772K, paused 21ms, total 21ms

02-05 12:20:11.933: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateTelephonySignalStrength[0]: iconList[iconLevel]=7f020298/zz_moto_stat_sys_signal_3_fully_wide iconLevel=3 mMSimMobileInetCondition=1 mMSimMobileInetConditionSB=1

02-05 12:20:11.935: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: subscription=0

02-05 12:20:11.936: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: dataSub=0

02-05 12:20:11.936: D/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): updateDataIcon[0]: SimState=READY

02-05 12:20:11.940: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174): notifySignalsChangedCallbacks[0]: isEmergencyOnly(0)=false enabled=true sim=(none)="(empty)" signal=zz_moto_stat_sys_signal_3_fully_wide="Três barras de sinal do telefone." roaming=(none)="Não está em roaming."

02-05 12:20:11.940: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174):  type=zz_moto_stat_sys_data_suspended_h_wide="3.5G" activity=(none)="(empty)"

02-05 12:20:11.940: I/SBar.MSimNetwCntrl(1174):  slot=1="1" network="Claro BR"

02-05 12:20:12.206: D/TCMD(497): NL - Read 56 bytes from update socket.

02-05 12:20:12.206: D/TCMD(497): NL - message type is RTM_NEWLINK

02-05 12:20:12.206: D/TCMD(497): Listening for incoming client connection request

02-05 12:20:12.208: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-BSS-ADDED 286

02-05 12:20:12.208: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-BSS-ADDED 286

02-05 12:20:12.208: D/MDMCTBK(408): reply_len: 40 reply is = IFNAME=wlan0 <3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 

02-05 12:20:12.208: D/MDMCTBK(408): Event received = CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS 

02-05 12:20:12.209: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:12.210: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=147461

02-05 12:20:12.211: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:12.211: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:12.211: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectModeState

02-05 12:20:12.212: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: DriverStartedState

02-05 12:20:12.212: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: SupplicantStartedState

02-05 12:20:12.242: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:12.243: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572

02-05 12:20:12.243: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:12.244: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:12.255: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X

02-05 12:20:12.268: V/StateManager(25087): startStateForResult class com.android.gallery3d.app.AlbumPage, 1

02-05 12:20:12.291: D/AutoHLR(25087): AutoHighlightReelBanner()

02-05 12:20:12.295: D/AlbumPage(25087): onSyncDone: ******** result=0

02-05 12:20:12.295: D/AutoHLR(25087): removeHighlightReelView()

02-05 12:20:12.295: D/AutoHLR(25087): dismiss

02-05 12:20:12.295: D/AutoHLR(25087): pause

02-05 12:20:12.295: D/AutoHLR(25087): setIsCancelled = true

02-05 12:20:12.317: I/GLRootView(25087): layout content pane 720x1184 (compensation 0)

02-05 12:20:12.320: D/AutoHLR(25087): removeHighlightReelView()

02-05 12:20:12.321: D/AutoHLR(25087): dismiss

02-05 12:20:12.321: D/AutoHLR(25087): pause

02-05 12:20:12.321: D/AutoHLR(25087): setIsCancelled = true

02-05 12:20:12.361: V/UlpEngine(1088): handleNetworkLocationUpdate. lat-30.0109053lon-51.194978accurancy 41.143

02-05 12:20:12.361: D/Ulp_jni(1088): send_network_location.

02-05 12:20:12.362: D/Ulp_jni(1088): Location CB invoked

02-05 12:20:12.362: E/LocSvc_libulp(1088): W/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF 

02-05 12:20:12.412: D/WifiService(1088): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@42a5b648}

02-05 12:20:12.553: D/dalvikvm(25087): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 22962K, 49% free 24578K/47944K, paused 21ms, total 21ms

02-05 12:20:12.581: I/SFPerfTracer(293):      triggers: (rate: 0:7) (5833 sw vsyncs) (0 skipped) (13:218282 vsyncs) (15:308686)

02-05 12:20:13.221: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: E msg.what=151572

02-05 12:20:13.221: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:13.222: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): processMsg: L2ConnectedState

02-05 12:20:13.253: D/WifiStateMachine(1088): handleMessage: X
```

Comment: Show the code where are you handling the `REQUEST_CODE`. I mean the `OnActivityResult` function

Comment: Added the onActionResult, thank you. Recalling that is not even chedando to onActionResult the fragment is terminated before. If I'm doing debug is terminated while I am selecting the file.

Comment: on whch line the app is terminating when you debug?

Comment: It ends when I am selecting the file. No longer more in my app.

Comment: please `debug` your code and show us the line where are you getting an `exception`

Comment: ok check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833562/activity-result-fragment-index-out-of-range-0x20001)

Comment: hello, your suggestion does not work.
The problem is not in return. Often the file selection works. What happens is that before selecting the file, my app already ended. I changed the log cat (no filter).